# Writing data into MySQL table with JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I have linked up a database to my Java application using the JDBC in Netbeans.
But whenever I try to write something from a TextField to a MySQL table, it doesn't work.

I have a pre-made class to make the database connection.

Here is my database class:

```
        package testswitch; 

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Maarten 
 */

public class Database {


public final static String DB_DRIVER_URL = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public final static String DB_DRIVER_PREFIX = "jdbc:mysql://";

private Connection connection = null;

public Database(String dataBaseName, String serverURL, String userName, String passWord) {
    try {
        // verify that a proper JDBC driver has been installed and linked
        if (!selectDriver(DB_DRIVER_URL)) {
            return;
        }

        if (serverURL == null || serverURL.isEmpty()) {
            serverURL = "localhost:3306";
        }

        // establish a connection to a named Database on a specified server
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_DRIVER_PREFIX + serverURL + "/" + dataBaseName, userName, passWord);
    } catch (SQLException eSQL) {
        logException(eSQL);
    }
}

private static boolean selectDriver(String driverName) {
    // Selects proper loading of the named driver for Database connections.
    // This is relevant if there are multiple drivers installed that match the JDBC type.
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        // Put all non-prefered drivers to the end, such that driver selection hits the first
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            Driver d = drivers.nextElement();
            if (!d.getClass().getName().equals(driverName)) {
                // move the driver to the end of the list
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
                DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        logException(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void executeNonQuery(String query) {
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException eSQL) {
        logException(eSQL);
    }
}

public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
    Statement statement;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);

        return result;
    } catch (SQLException eSQL) {
        logException(eSQL);
    }

    return null;
}

private static void logException(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());

    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And here's my JavaFX controller.
What I want is that when the "handle" button is pressed, that the data filled in the TextField gets inserted into the database.

```
package testswitch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import testswitch.Database;

/**
 *
 * @author Maarten
 */
public class gebruikerToevoegenController {

    //TextFields
    @FXML
    private TextField FXVoornaam, FXTussenvoegsel, FXAchternaam, FXGebruikersnaam;
    @FXML
    private TextField FXWachtwoord, FXEmail, FXTelefoonnummer;

    //Boolean checkbox positie
    @FXML
    private CheckBox ManagerPosition;
    @FXML
    private Button gebruikerButton;

    public final String DB_NAME = "testDatabase";
    public final String DB_SERVER = "localhost:3306";
    public final String DB_ACCOUNT = "root";
    public final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";

    Database database = new Database(DB_NAME, DB_SERVER, DB_ACCOUNT, DB_PASSWORD);

    public void handle(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {

        String query = "INSERT INTO testDatabase.Gebruikers (Voornaam) VALUES " + FXVoornaam.getText();
        try {
            database.executeQuery(query);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Why isn't this code working" is off-topic here. Use a debugger to find out, or describe what errors you got and what you tried to fix them: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried running the "query" String directly on your DBMS to see that the statement itself actually works? Also, what does "result" contain in your "executeQuery" method (anything useful?)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running query, and it works. I think result holds the connection to the database and executes the query onto it, correct me if I'm wrong, and as I mentioned, its a pre-made class

Comment: Don't just "swallow" exceptions when you're debugging. Adding something like `e.printStackTrace(System.err)` in the catch block should give you a better idea what's going on... BTW: I doubt that the string is properly quoted in the query and the values should be inside brackets. Better use `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add like this in JavaFx :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO testDatabase.Gebruikers (Voornaam) VALUES ('{FXVoornaam.getText()}') ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly it isn't working sadly.

Comment: I don't know why you'd write something like this in java but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work...

Comment: see in JavaFx you can add this method for a textbox , eg : textbox.rawText()

Answer (score 0):

The string in your SQL query doesn't seem to be properly quoted. It's best to use `PreparedStatement` for this scenario:

```
public class Database {

    public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String query) throws SQLException {
         return connection.prepareStatement(query);
    }

    ...
```

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {

    String query = "INSERT INTO testDatabase.Gebruikers (Voornaam) VALUES (?);";
    PreparedStatement statement = database.prepareStatement(query);
    try {
        statement.setString(1, FXVoornaam.getText());
        statement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // log info somewhere at least until it's properly tested/
         // you implement a better way of handling the error
         e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO testDatabase.Gebruikers(Voornaam) 
VALUES('" + FXVoornaam.getText() + "')";
```